How should I prioritize whom to ask for a letter of recommendation based on expertise and academic title?
I’m applying for PhD programs in Artificial Intelligence, and I’m currently in doubt about which professors to ask for letters of recommendation.
Here’s my situation:

My master’s thesis professor hasn’t replied to my emails regarding a
letter of recommendation, and during the thesis, I only interacted
with a PhD student rather than the professor. This professor also
didn’t attend my thesis defence, which makes me question whether I
should keep waiting or look for other options.
My bachelor’s thesis professor is very supportive and has already
agreed to write me a strong letter of recommendation.

Now, I’m considering asking another professor for a third letter. I’m wondering how to prioritize whom to ask, especially considering the field and subfield they specialize in, as well as their academic standing.
My main questions are:

How important is it that the professor works specifically in the
same field (e.g., artificial intelligence) or even more
specifically, in the subfield (e.g., computer vision) I want to
pursue for my PhD?
Does the academic rank of the professor (e.g., associate professor
vs. full professor) affect the strength of the recommendation, or is
the content of the letter more important?
Should I prioritize getting a letter from someone who knows me well
but works in a somewhat different area, or from someone in my
specific field but who knows me less well?

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Likely duplicate of https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12959/who-should-write-a-recommendation-letter?rq=1

I don't believe it properly answers my questions because I also have a problem my supervisor of my master's thesis is not responding to my emails.
